# What do you call a person who enacts, lives, or portrays the book he has read?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, I have known a statesman that used all his political strategies and tactics based on a certain book (self help). One can understand the reason of every move he makes and even predict the next tactic because he knows the content of the book by heart. The book's genre is self help and if I'm not mistaken it is a fiction book.

I don't know if "living proof" is the exact term. I doubt it.

Comment: "Living proof" is the closest that I can come up with. "He is living proof that the strategies described in the book do in fact work."

Comment: Is this supposed to be a positive or negative descriptor?  A *mindless automaton* comes to mind for the negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Embodiment** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embodiment)

> someone or something that is a perfect representative or example of a quality, idea, etc.
>   *"She's the embodiment of all our hopes."*

*"He's the **embodiment** of everything said in that book"*
*"men who greatly **embodied** the idealism of American life"* — A. M. Schlesinger b1917

Such a person can be called an **embodier**.